# when adding post in wordpress the post coming on the top of the page not below the content where i wanted

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using a WordPress theme.

In the home page i added the banner on top and some text below of it. Then i added a new post  from the post Tab from the Dashboard menu. But when I am preview the site the post coming on the top of the page despite of below the content or the banner image.

Check this link [enter link description here](http://satz13.com/)

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in, the description you gave is to vague, It sounds to me you have a CSS issue, which is probably in relation to the image. More info would help.

Comment: its not the css issue, i have checked it. Somehow the post coming directly on the top even if i put more posts. The posts comes first then the main content comes after of it.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem of the post coming on the top of the page is **published date**. The new post comes on the top and old posts below of it, I just changed the published date of old post into new date in posts settings.

Its done now, the post(content) which i wanted on the top of the page.